# Positioning arrow on the middle of a div

Tags: html, css

I need to position arrow in the top and middle and of the div. The width of div changes dynamically and when i use left:%50 to position arrow in the middle then it adds the width of arrow and because of that the result is not satisfactory.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/cLrcqww1/)

**CODE**

```css
#wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1px;
  color: #000;
  border: 0px solid #cc3333;
  background-color: grey;
}
#wrapper em.out {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -7px;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  border-left: 7px dashed transparent;
  border-right: 7px dashed transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper em.inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -7px;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  border-left: 7px dashed transparent;
  border-right: 7px dashed transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <em class="out"></em>
  <em class="inner"></em>
  <div>
    <div style="margin:1px;background-color:white;">
      <option>------John------</option>
    </div>
    <div style="margin:1px;background-color:white;">
      <option>------David------</option>
    </div>
    <div style="margin:1px;background-color:white;">
      <option>------Jennifer------</option>
    </div>
    <div style="margin:1px;background-color:white;">
      <option>------Sue------</option>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add `transform: translate(-50%);` in `#wrapper em.inner`& `#wrapper em.out` class !! as simple as that :)

```css
#wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1px;
  color: #000;
  border: 0px solid #cc3333;
  background-color: grey;
}
#wrapper em.out {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -7px;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  border-left: 7px dashed transparent;
  border-right: 7px dashed transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
#wrapper em.inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -7px;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  border-left: 7px dashed transparent;
  border-right: 7px dashed transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <em class="out"></em>
  <em class="inner"></em>
  <div>
    <div style="margin:1px;background-color:white;">
      <option>------John Doe------</option>
    </div>
    <div style="margin:1px;background-color:white;">
      <option>------David------</option>
    </div>
    <div style="margin:1px;background-color:white;">
      <option>------Jennifer------</option>
    </div>
    <div style="margin:1px;background-color:white;">
      <option>------Sue------</option>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that is great.really nice.